# Successful survival strategies for academic departments threatened with closure

Tags: politics

Every now and again, academic departments are threatened with closure by university administrations.

One current example: Pure Mathematics in Leicester is under threat of closure (making academic staff redundant).

What successful strategies have departments been able to use to see off threats like this?

Comment: It is pretty hard to imagine a university without a math department. Have you got a reference for the situation at Leicester? Who will teach math to science and engineering students?

Comment: @Buffy In the UK, service courses are not common. In most universities (NB: not a claim that I can actually back up - it's just that I know of exactly one that doesn't fit the pattern), the engineering department teaches its students the mathematics that they need for their course, and similarly for other departments.

Comment: @Buffy here is pretty much all I know: https://www.ipetitions.com/petition/mathematics-is-not-redundant

Comment: How is Leicester funded? Is the majority of it public monies, with student fees and grants only a part of it or the other way round? I can't seem to find the information.

Comment: https://le.ac.uk/about/info/publications/financial-statements for 2018-19 says
£330.9 million total income;
£168.2 million income from tuition fees;
£58.1 million research income;
£2.0 million new endowments and donations;
£190.1 million staff costs.

Comment: The same question was asked on MO some time ago.  Check out the (many) answers there: https://mathoverflow.net/q/63221/6518

Comment: @Buffy Almost all UK universities, Leicester included, are heavily funded by general taxation via the funding and research councils (government-appointed bodies). The largest non-government source of funds for most universities (with some exceptions for, eg Cambridge, who have income from historical wealth) is student fees, which are (for domestic students) paid primarily via the government-run Student Loans Company, and underwritten by the government. International student fees are also a significant income source for some universities.

Comment: A better question would be:
how you can a department provide value to its student, the university and the wider community, beyond its research output and lectures?

Comment: Outside of academia, the general rule to follow when you smell a closing coming is that it's time to polish up your curriculum vitae and get it into circulation.  It's easier to find a new job when you already have one, and it's easier before the market gets flooded with your colleagues.

Comment: 1. Do an IPO 2. Hedge funds will short you. 3. Mention your department's stock on r/WallstreetBets 4. Rake in the fame and money :-)

Comment: As a positive example, La Trobe University in Australia reversed its closure of the Greek unit after publicity caused a rise in enrolments and a state government top-up https://campusmorningmail.com.au/vc-jacobs-to-leave-unsw/#headline4

Comment: I don't think this question has a general answer. Everything depends on local politics: Who is pushing for the closure? What is driving it? Why has department X been chosen for cuts, and not department Y? Do the numbers add up?

Comment: If there's a Dept of *Pure* Mathematics, is there a Dept of *Applied* Mathematics it can merge with, to become the Dept of Pure and Applied Mathematics?

Comment: @avid In addition to those questions, there's also the question of who has the formal power to _decide_ to make academic staff redundant (as opposed to merely being able to _propose_ or _promote_ the idea).  I had a quick scan of the statutes and ordinances of the University of Leicester, and that quick scan was insufficient to be able to form a clear view on that question.

Comment: @RonJohn OP is not entirely accurate. In Leicester, the department in question is "Mathematics and Actuarial Science", and there's no question of closing it entirely. However, they plan to make about 1/3 of what in normal circumstances I would refer to as the "permanent staff" redundant, solely based on their research being in pure maths.

Comment: See this twitter thread for more details of what went wrong at Leicester: https://twitter.com/leicesterucu/status/1354398863218647041

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- Once you are threatened with closure, it is probably too late to fix your problems.
- Increase enrollment of new students with marketing.
- Increase retention of students with better teaching and extracurricular experiences.
- Seek donations.
- Find a new source of revenue.
- Unionize.  A union contract can force cross-subsidies from money-making departments to money-losing departments instead of closure.  However, this will not work if there are no money-making departments.

These decisions are all about money, and there's no easy way to get money.

A more detailed answer: https://ep3guide.org/toolkit

Comment: This is probably incorrect for a publicly (i.e. tax) funded institution. The problem is political and the unwillingness of the political class to think broadly enough about the future.

Comment: @Buffy "The problem is political and the unwillingness of the political class to think broadly enough about the future." - I do not see a change on the horizon. Such tide changes happen every 30-40 years. The pandemic may initiate such a tide change in topics like pharmacy, medicine, epidemiology etc. Another tide change was triggered by the Sputnik shock (in the 50s, not the recent one).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, yes, it is easy to get discouraged, but it means we have to push harder on the levers of power. Failing to educate young people is a sure strategy to national decline.

Comment: @Buffy I can assure you that I do my best, but in the end it is not the effort of one or more or even many people who do, but the situation that suddenly makes it possible. Suitable people to do so are almost always around. The element of scarcity is in the timing, the overall mood and setting, almost never in the people (except in very rare circumstances).

Comment: @Buffy  It's not clear that publicly funded schools are really publicly funded anymore.   The State of Texas, which used to underwrite most of UT's budget is now contributing essentially nothing.  UT operates like a private school at this point, working mostly with big donors and charging high tuition to make the school run.

Comment: @Buffy I've never heard of a publicly funded institution where politicians had any influence over *which* department was closed.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. But politicians can squeeze public universities to the point where such decisions become necessary. The general overhead of running a department (office space, clerical staff, etc) may force terrible zero-sum decisions.

Comment: @B.Goddard is right.  Public funding is usually enrollment-linked or zero.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This is in the UK, not the US. Things are very different in this regard.

Comment: @Buffy true, this is a US focused answer, as public unis have seen drastic cuts in the US since 2007. It's exactly why you see all the rock walls, athletic facilities and other flashy things designed to grab the attention of potential students.

Comment: @user3482749 the op gave that as an example, but they never indicated the were only interested in UK / euro unis.  In the US this is going to be (already is) a major problem because universities here are completely broke.  Bankruptcies and acquisitions / mergers are going through the roof and it means programs getting slashed and huge downsizing of academic positions.

Comment: 'Increase enrollment of new students'  As a potential solution, that depends on the assumption that the marginal cost to the university of providing education to each additional student is lower than the regulatory cap on the tuition fees each student can be charged.  There are some English universities where that assumption would be wildly wrong.

Comment: @DanielHatton Do those universities receive an incentive to enroll students from government?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist In some subjects (mathematics not being among them), there's such an incentive through the "high-cost courses" element of the OfS teaching grant.  Other elements of the OfS teaching grant provide such incentives if a higher-than-usual proportion of the students being enrolled are mature students, or are from deprived areas, or are disabled, or have weak pre-university academic qualifications.  But none of those funding streams fully cover the government's estimate of the _additional_ costs associated with those subjects and student characteristics.

Answer (score 32):

This is, in fact, the *second* time that Leicester's maths department has faced these kind of threats. The previous time (in 2016), they backed down following a petition and other objections organised by a variety of mathematicians.

Comment: Interesting - I had assumed petitions would be ignored, as they don't seem to affect universities financially, and any reputational damage among stakeholders the university cares  about (which would exclude the academic discipline concerned) would probably be minimal. Is it clear that petitions and other PR efforts have been effective in the past?

Comment: Well, Leicester threatened to do something similar in 2016, and it delayed it for four years, so it has certainly worked at least once in Leicester specifically.

Comment: @user108903 it all depends where on the scale you are. If it's a marginal decision it's much easier to tip the scales with moderate amounts of pushback, even if it's just a petition and/or some sit ins.  Sometimes, the initial proposals are just 'trial balloons' or negotiating tools. it's a much different story if the money just isn't there and they absolutely have to make deep cuts to continue operating.

Answer (score 17):

Check with whatever accreditation outfit your school uses.  I was once at an engineering school and the engineering faculty really thought that they could teach the "math their students needed" and would really liked to have gotten rid of the math department.  But whatever accreditation body they used to have an accredited engineering program insisted that they have a real math department staffed by real mathematicians.

So the answer might be "if you close your math department, you'll lose your accreditation." And who wants to send their kid to an unaccredited school?

Comment: I don't know how Brexit affected accreditation, but I was under the impression that accreditation wasn't that important in the UK.

Comment: @MSalters accreditation in the American sense doesn't really exist for the most part, it's web of trust backed by government organized evaluations of procedure. Having said that, some of the more vocational engineering type degrees are audited by professional societies.

Comment: @origimbo My engineering professor told me in Canada that it's a web of trust back by corporations. The corporations told the government "back off, just let us do our business" and the government said "yessir". Makes me wonder who is going to teach the physicists math.

Comment: Closing "Pure mathematics department", is not the same as closing "math department". Please see my answer below in case looking for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, let me say that I find what is happening at Leicester utterly horrible.

However, the truth is that pure mathematicians do, *in general*, tend to have a disdain for applied work. In not a few places "mathematics departments", which originally contained within them areas such as statistics or computer science, tended to eject any type of applied field and let them create their own departments, while leaving only the purest of the purest within the administrative division labelled "mathematics". This attitude is now coming back to bite them.

As a long-term strategy, it might serve mathematics departments well to maintain more diversity in their research focus, and not segregate "pure" and "applied" research. After all, there isn't really a very clear line between "pure" and "applied": a single researcher may do some of both, and some types of research touch on both. If the University of Leicester did not have two clearly separated administrative divisions labelled "pure math" and "applied math", then they could not pull this off.

This is not meant as criticism, but as a pragmatic suggestion.

Comment: "This attitude is now coming back to bite them." Very well said, but is not just an attitude, it is an entire discipline. The difference between pure and applied maths is very well defined, and it has its history, being the pure math born in the thirties and for very specific reasons. Justifying the existence of "Pure mathematics" has been debated since then. Please see my answer below for more details who would not fit this comment.

Answer (score 6):

If the academic department offers courses that directly contribute to the university's mission and vision, then this can be used to justify its continued existence.  For example, a religiously-affiliated university would not close a theology department even if the department has dwindling enrollment.

Comment: I saw a news story recently saying that a religious university was, in fact, closing its religion department.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Sounds like an interesting story. Any details you remember that would help in finding this university?

Comment: Well, Liberty University is cutting back in its Divinity department.  That would be a bit like MIT de-emphasizing engineering: https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2019/06/17/liberty-university-cuts-divinity-faculty

Answer (score 6):

https://www.nbcnews.com/news/education/crisis-looming-u-s-colleges-not-just-because-pandemic-n1235338

At least in the US, the outlook for many universities is utterly dire.  Enrollments have plummeted due to the virus, but at least in the US education has been headed towards a major correction for some time.   Many will go bankrupt, or be gobbled in an acquisition or merger.  Mergers and acquisitions almost always mean redundancies, either by thinning a department or eliminating it entirely.

Thus, the answer to the OP is that it greatly depends on why exactly a department might be eliminated. In some cases there may be strategies that can be employed to save a program if it's a marginal case (such as the petition mentioned in another answer). However, in many cases the best thing you can do if the writing is on the wall is to polish the resume and get out ahead of everyone else.

Answer (score -3):

Making the studied subject useful at something would be a good start.

In the specific case, the definition of "pure mathematics" deserves an historical introduction, to make clear it has nothing to do with the problem-solving mathematics. It is a subject that was founded only in the thirties by the Bourbaki group in France. The group was chasing the goal of finding a complete and coherent foundation of mathematical analysis, since few members of the groups had found some counterexamples in the Gourstat's book used back then.

The complete detachment from physics, and consequent creation of theories descending only from axioms, where no single problem is ever solved, is what characterises the "pure" approach established back then.

Fortunately or not, Goedel incompleteness theorem wiped out the possibility of the coherent and complete theory sought by Bourbaki for good. Despite this event, the branch of "pure mathematics", as it fits very well with the academic environment and the need of a hierarchy not based on merit (if no problem is solved, who will tell who deserves a promotion and how does not), is still a subject per se, and it had become as well as a pedagogical methodology (and a detrimental one, according to many).

- [https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/bourbaki.pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/bourbaki.pdf)
- [https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/~munsteg/arnold.html](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/%7Emunsteg/arnold.html)

Interesting to notice that there have never been such a thing as "pure mathematics" before Bourbaki, having maths always something applied to solve real problems for the entire history of humanity: finding algorithms, and generalisations only when it was possible to apply a solution found in one instance to solve a wider range of problems. Archimedes, Gauss or Euler would have not understood the question: "are you a pure mathematician?".

To the commenters distressed at the idea of a university without a math department, they can be reassure that "pure mathematics" has nothing to do with the mathematics they have studied for the A-level, or the mathematics they know of as a tool to solve problems.

Besides the theoretical groundlesness of pure mathematics, as mathematically proven by Goedel, the "pure" mathematics studies certainly have a detrimental effects on their students. I recently interviewed a candidate with a pure mathematics background, graduated with full marks with a thesis on a subject he was not able to explain during the interview, who turned out to have never heard of graph theory. Also he heard of the existence of differential equations, but as something for another department, not for him, so he had never solved one.

There is the curious situation of an increasing amount of industries thirsty for mathematical talents, as problem solvers and algorithms developer, and the "pure" mathematics department is producing graduates with the title of mathematicians who are crippled by too much useless theory, lost in a machinery of details, and unable to solve anything or compute anything.
Leaving the abstract manipulation of symbols, and teaching Algorithms and Differential Equations ("with their applications", as purists like to put it) instead of axiomatic theories closed in boxes, would be the best strategy to keep the maths departments alive, and provide students with capabilities other than knowledge.

---- Edit:

I must have touched a point, since all my posts have been downvoted shortly after writing this one. Bringing down the reputation of the author instead of talking about ideas, now, that's a strategy never used before! .-)

Comment: I suppose you don't think there should be philosophy or literature departments either?

Comment: I think there should be, as long as they are not called "pure engineering", and as long as they provide students with tools and knowledge to face the outside world, and be independent thinkers.

Comment: To put it in context, a graduated mathematician who never heard about Graph theory is like a philosopher who never heard of Plato, because 80 years ago someone decided that "pure philosophy" must be only the study of abstract ideas with no historical context. 
Or a graduated classical guitar player who never heard of Segovia, because the conservatory decided that music is only the study of scales.

Comment: I disagree.  Graph theory is a relatively new branch of mathematics, and not historically all that important.  I'd be disappointed in a philosopher who had never heard of Heidegger, but wouldn't consider it disqualifying.  (I'll add that Wittgenstein was quite ignorant of the history of philosophy.)

Comment: Euclid was a pure mathematician.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo You make a point with Elements of Euclid, under the assumption that each time the author writes "axioms" then he/she is "pure", otherwise "applied". I disagree with this. The discriminating factor is in the final goal. In the Elements, Euclid wanted to provide a manual for computations with ruler and compass, and used the axioms to remove useless details. Axioms and theorems where not its goal (in fact he assumed multiple times that two circle can intersect in two points, without proving it. This would have him rejected by Bourbaki, but it bothered nobody for 2000+ years).

Comment: "Graph theory is a relatively new branch of mathematics, and not historically all that important" Sorry... It dates back to 1736, it is a fundamental component of many prominent search algorithms (for example google), and there is a very wide range of open problems that would make you rich and famous if solved. Also I would seriously question a philosopher who never heard of Heidegger, as I studied it while attending scientific high-school.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133258/discussion-between-alexander-woo-and-sef).